# Do Apache Phoenix support stored procedures? If yes how to impliment it?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

How to execute stored procedure in phoenix?

If not then please tell alternate for stored procedure in phoenix

Thanks

Comment: I found https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_orm.html pho library , but not getting how to execute stored procedure

Comment: probably the closest http://phoenix.apache.org/udf.html